# D3.js Updating onclick other element

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have a issue with d3.js i am trying to make a grid where every line have "two state" (two color) as you can see. I generate the elements and it works great (maybe i could do it easier). My problem is that i need a "transformation". Which would be that if you click to a rectangle every sides of the rectangle change color.
My question specifically, is how can i make this function?

Thank you in advance.

Here is where im stuck:

```js
// grid basic variables
var dimension = 10,
 width = 50,
 height = 50;

function gridData() {
 var data = new Array();

 // rectangle variables
 var rectXpos = 0,
   rectYpos = 0,
   rectWidth = width,
   rectHeight = height;
  click = 0;

 // iterate for rows
 for (var row = 0; row < dimension; row++) {

  // iterate for cells/columns inside rows
  for (var column = 0; column < dimension; column++) {
   // rectClass = "rect" + rectXpos.toString() + rectYpos.toString();
   data.push({
    x: rectXpos,
    y: rectYpos,
    width: rectWidth,
    height: rectHeight,
    // class: rectClass,
    click: click
   });

   // increment the x position. I.e. move it over by 50 (width variable)
   rectXpos += rectWidth;
  }
  // reset the x position after a row is complete
  rectXpos = 0;
  // increment the y position for the next row. Move it down 50 (height variable)
  rectYpos += rectHeight;
 }
 return data;
}

var gridData = gridData();
// I like to log the data to the console for quick debugging
console.log(gridData);

var grid = d3.select("#grid")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", width*dimension)
 .attr("height",height*dimension);

var rect = grid.selectAll(".square")
 .data(gridData)
 .enter().append("rect")
 .attr("class","rect")
 .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
 .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
 .attr("width", function(d) { return d.width; })
 .attr("height", function(d) { return d.height; })
 .style("fill", "#f2f2f2")
 .style("stroke", "#fff")
 .on('click', function(d) {
  d.click ++;
  d3.select(".vline" + d.x.toString() + d.y.toString() + (d.x + 50).toString() + d.y.toString()).style("stroke","#f4363f");
  // d3.select(".vline" + d.x.toString() + (d.y + 50).toString() + (d.x + 50).toString() + (d.y + 50).toString()).style("stroke","#f4363f");
  // d3.select(".hline" + d.x.toString() + d.y.toString() + d.x.toString() + (d.y + 50).toString()).style("stroke","#f4363f");
  // d3.select(".hline" + (d.x + 50).toString() + d.y.toString() + (d.x + 50).toString() + (d.y + 50).toString()).style("stroke","#f4363f");
 });

function hlinegriddata() {
 var data = new Array();

 // line variables
 var hlineX1 = 0,
   hlineY1 = 0,
   hlineX2 = 0,
   hlineY2 = 50,
  click = 0;

 var lineLength = width;

 for (var row = 0; row < dimension; row++) {

  // iterate for cells/columns inside rows
  for (var column = 0; column < dimension + 1; column++) {
   hlineClass = "hline" + hlineX1.toString() + hlineY1.toString() + hlineX2.toString() + hlineY2.toString();
   data.push({
    x1: hlineX1,
    y1: hlineY1,
    x2: hlineX2,
    y2: hlineY2,
    class: hlineClass,
    click: click
   });

        // increment the x position for the next line
        hlineX1 += lineLength;
        hlineX2 += lineLength;
  }

  // reset the x position after a row is complete
  hlineX1 = 0;
  hlineX2 = 0;

  // increment the y position for the next row. Move it down 50 (height variable)
  hlineY1 += lineLength;
  hlineY2 += lineLength;
 }
 return data;
}

var hlinegriddata = hlinegriddata();
// I like to log the data to the console for quick debugging
console.log(hlinegriddata);

var hline = grid.selectAll(".hline")
 .data(hlinegriddata)
 .enter().append("line")
 .attr("class", function(d) { return d.class; })
 .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.x1; })
 .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.y1; })
 .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.x2; })
 .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.y2; })
 .style("stroke", "#fff")
 .style("stroke-width", "4")
 .style("cursor", "pointer")
 .on('click', function(d) {
  d.click ++;
       if ((d.click)%2 == 0 ) { d3.select(this).style("stroke","#fff"); }
    if ((d.click)%2 == 1 ) { d3.select(this).style("stroke","#f4363f"); }
    });

function vlinegriddata() {
 var data = new Array();

 // line variables
 var vlineX1 = 0,
   vlineY1 = 0,
   vlineX2 = 50,
   vlineY2 = 0,
  click = 0;

 var lineLength = width;

 // iterate for rows
 for (var row = 0; row < dimension; row++) {

  // iterate for cells/columns inside rows
  for (var column = 0; column < dimension + 1; column++) {
   vlineClass = "vline" + vlineX1.toString() + vlineY1.toString() + vlineX2.toString() + vlineY2.toString();
   data.push({
    x1: vlineX1,
    y1: vlineY1,
    x2: vlineX2,
    y2: vlineY2,
    class: vlineClass,
    click: click
   });

        // increment the x position for the next line
        vlineY1 += lineLength;
        vlineY2 += lineLength;
  }

  // reset the x position after a row is complete
  vlineY1 = 0;
  vlineY2 = 0;
  // increment the y position for the next row. Move it down 50 (height variable)
  vlineX1 += lineLength;
  vlineX2 += lineLength;
 }
 return data;
}

var vlinegriddata = vlinegriddata();
// I like to log the data to the console for quick debugging
console.log(vlinegriddata);

var vline = grid.selectAll(".vline")
 .data(vlinegriddata)
 .enter().append("line")
 .attr("class", function(d) { return d.class; })
 .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.x1; })
 .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.y1; })
 .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.x2; })
 .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.y2; })
 .style("stroke", "white")
 .style("stroke-width", "4")
 .style("cursor", "pointer")
 // .on("click", function(){var nextColor = this.style.stroke == "white" ? "magenta" : "white";
    //         d3.select(this).style("stroke", nextColor);});
 .on('click', function(d) {
       d.click ++;
       if ((d.click)%2 == 0 ) { d3.select(this).style("stroke","#fff"); }
    if ((d.click)%2 == 1 ) { d3.select(this).style("stroke","#f4363f"); }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the purpose of all those lines. You could just stroke the `rect`:

```
.on('click', function(d) {
  s.click ++;
  d3.select(this)
    .style("stroke", "#f4363f")
    .style("stroke-width", "1px");
});
```

Running code:

```js
// grid basic variables
var dimension = 10,
 width = 50,
 height = 50;

function gridData() {
 var data = new Array();

 // rectangle variables
 var rectXpos = 0,
   rectYpos = 0,
   rectWidth = width,
   rectHeight = height;
  click = 0;

 // iterate for rows
 for (var row = 0; row < dimension; row++) {

  // iterate for cells/columns inside rows
  for (var column = 0; column < dimension; column++) {
   // rectClass = "rect" + rectXpos.toString() + rectYpos.toString();
   data.push({
    x: rectXpos,
    y: rectYpos,
    width: rectWidth,
    height: rectHeight,
    // class: rectClass,
    click: click
   });

   // increment the x position. I.e. move it over by 50 (width variable)
   rectXpos += rectWidth + 1;
  }
  // reset the x position after a row is complete
  rectXpos = 0;
  // increment the y position for the next row. Move it down 50 (height variable)
  rectYpos += rectHeight + 1;
 }
 return data;
}

var gridData = gridData();
// I like to log the data to the console for quick debugging
console.log(gridData);

var grid = d3.select("#grid")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", width*dimension)
 .attr("height",height*dimension);

var rect = grid.selectAll(".square")
 .data(gridData)
 .enter().append("rect")
 .attr("class","rect")
 .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
 .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
 .attr("width", function(d) { return d.width; })
 .attr("height", function(d) { return d.height; })
 .style("fill", "#f2f2f2")
 .style("stroke", "#fff")
 .on('click', function(d) {
  d.click ++;
    d3.select(this)
      .style("stroke", "#f4363f")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px");
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid"></div>
```

Comment: Sadly that shouldnt be good for me @Mark. 
This is a physics demo, and the concept is that i can change the color of the line if i click on it, and when i click on a rectangle i want to change all of the sides (line around it) color, and always change to the other color. So the line is white or red, and only the line color change, and i can click on the line or rectangle.
https://jsfiddle.net/khlan/o53Lqqox/
This fiddle nearly works good. Two problem left:
1. if click on the rectangle the sides change the color to red, but not back, 
2. if before 1 line was red it not change to white